# Android Subclass Listview problem

Tags: java, android

I have a subclass of ListView.  My only problem is I can't get it to work (not the listview code, but the code to *use* the listview.  Android won't inflate it (app crashes).  I'm sure there is a simple way to get this to work, but I don't know how.

```
PullToRefreshListView list;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.cliplistmain);

    context = this;
    list = (PullToRefreshListView)findViewById(R.id.clipListMain);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    list.setOnScrollListener(this);

    list.setOnRefreshListener(new OnRefreshListener(){
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() 
        {
            ClipStore.getInstance().getClips(SugarLoafContext.currentCamera);
        }
    });

    Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.findclipsbtn);
    btn.setOnClickListener(this);
    SugarLoafContext.lastView = SugarLoafContext.LAST_VIEW_CLIP_LIST;

}
```

Here is my xml:

```
<ListView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/clipListMain" >
```

Comment: So what does your logcat give you when it crashes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only a part of your layout xml file right, so you do have header and namespace information in your XML.

I guess you get a ClassCastException or similar right? Since you've got a `ListView` in your xml but cast it into your `PullToRefreshListView` class.

Your layout xml (i.e. `./res/layout/foo.xml`) should be something like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.yourpackage.foo.PullToRefreshListView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.yourpackage.foo"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/clipListMain" />
```

Comment: I revised the xml according to what you suggested and get: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.logitech.sugarloaf/com.logitech.sugarloaf.ClipListView}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ListView

Comment: Of course you have to replace the `com.yourpackage.foo` by your package name.

Comment: But I don't know what your `ClipListView` class is, i guessed your custom ListView is the `PullToRefreshListView`.
But anyway, if this codeline in your code
`list = (PullToRefreshListView)findViewById(R.id.clipListMain);`
is correct than your View with the id clipListMain hast to be of type `PullToRefreshListView` and not of `ListView`

Answer (score 1):

IMO you forget about adding this subclass name to xml config

Comment: Its not an activity, so why would I put it in the manifest? Or are you talking about some other file?